# How to Parse a Java String containing HTML element as JsonObject?

Tags: java, html, json

Hi I am having a Java String with following value received from HTTPRequest

```
{SubRefNumber:"3243 ",QBType:"-----",Question:"<p><img title="format.jpg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB..."></img></p>"};
```

As the String contains HTML elements as part of it,while i try to parse the String as JsonObject as below (quesRow is the variable with above String as value)

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(quesRow);
```

I get parse error

> org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 103 of {SubRefNumber:"3243.....

I need to parse the HTML elements within Question Key as a seperate data from this JSONString. is there any way to handle this scenario? Please Guide...TIA

Comment: Whatever is sending you that is bugged; fix the bug there, don't try to work around it on the other side because that'll be incredibly complicated here: HTML is not regular, so trying to figure out where the HTML ends and the borked JSON continues is very much not trivial.

Comment: Agreed, the HTML is making the JSON invalid because of the extra quite marks messing up the JSON property string. Whoever created that JSON made a bad job of it and presumably didn't use a proper serialiser

Comment: @ADyson  Okay Sorry...I am newbie to JS..Henceforth not sure how to construct a JSON String in Java Script to include a HTML String inside it...I have tried some escape functions on html String before adding it to JSON string but Still i didnt get Exepcted result....CAn u Pls guide me on how to construct a valid JSON string that will have HTML as part of it...

Comment: Java or JavaScript? They are [**very** different](https://www.seguetech.com/java-vs-javascript-difference/). But if you google "[your language here] create JSON" I'd be surprised if you didn't get lots of results showing you how to properly construct a JSON object in your chosen language. The basic rule is "never create any JSON by manually joining strings together. Always use a serialiser to convert a native object (or array) of your programming language in to a JSON string. Then you won't get any silly syntax errors like these.

Comment: For example, this is the first result on google for "Java create JSON". http://appsdeveloperblog.com/java-into-json-json-into-java-all-possible-examples/ . It's been a long time since I did any Java (certainly before JSON was a popular thing), but it looks to me like that would show you what to do.

Comment: If you really mean JavaScript, then [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A valid JSON does not contain an unescaped quotation mark (") inside a string (See RFC 7159 Chapter 7 - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-9).

There are different options to escape the quotation mark in your source string, already when putting it into the JSON string parameter:

- escape with a backslash - "
- escape as unicode sequence - \u0022